# ModuleNotFoundError: Failed to import modules from directory on distributed system

Tags: python, module, environment-variables, distributed

I am working on a distributed system (yarn container), my IDE is Jupyterlab, in addition I have access to a bash terminal. I have several .py scripts in a distinct directory (with **init**.py), i try to import them as modules in my Notebook.

So far I tried this in bash terminal:

```
RPATH=$(pwd)
PPATH=$(pwd)'/src' # /src is the module folder
echo $RPATH
echo $PPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$PPATH
export ROOTPATH=$RPATH
echo $PYTHONPATH
echo $ROOTPATH
conda env config vars set PYTHONPATH=$PPATH
conda env config vars set ROOTPATH=$RPATH
```

And in the notebook itself i tried to set the environment variables by hand:

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH']= '/data/yarn/local_dirs/usercache/{user}/appcache/{application_id}/{container_id}/tmp/{working directory}/src'
os.environ['ROOT_DIR']= '/data/yarn/local_dirs/usercache/{user}/appcache/{application_id}/{container_id}/tmp/{working directory}'
```

This gives me repeatedly:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named {modulename}
```

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Python reads `PYTHONPATH` as part of **initializing** `sys.path`, but updates to the former will not be reflected in the latter (unless you start a Python subprocess).